# Firebase - No properties to serialize found on class

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a class like this:

```
class dataModel {
    String id, name;
    Integer count;

    dataModel() {}
}
```

And I add data from Firebase.

```
mDatabase.addValueEventListener(mListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            dataSet.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(dataModel.class));
            //...
        }
});
```

When I run the app as debug, there is no problem. But after it is released, app crashes with the error:

```
com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.my.package.dataModel
```

I have *minifyEnabled* ***true***

Answer (score 22, accepted):

To solve this, your class needs to implement the [Serializable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html) interface:

```
class dataModel implements Serializable {}
```

You also need to add a contructor with three arguments. Your class should look like this:

```
class dataModel implements Serializable {
    private String id, name;
    private Integer count;
    @ServerTimestamp
    private Date time;

    dataModel() {}

    dataModel(String id, String name, Integer count) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.count = count;
    }
}
```

If the date is `null`, it will have the server-generated timestamp. So you don't need to do set the value for it. Please also see the `annotation` used to mark a `Date` field to be populated with a server timestamp.

Also very important, don't forget to add `public getters`.

and the other requirement will be to add `-keepclassmembers class com.yourcompany.models.** { *; }` in proguard-rules.pro.

As said [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/start/#proguard).

Comment: @Dika Just edited my answer with the other approach. Hope you reconsider upvoting the answer.

Comment: done. sorry for late reply. And I edited your answer

Comment: @AlexMamo `com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: No properties to serialize found on class com.packagename.models.d` but there is no such class in models folder

Comment: Tks for the second last line