# Android Play Billing Library Proguard Rule?

Tags: android, in-app-billing, android-proguard

I implemented Inapp purchases using Play Billing Library.
I am storing the Purchase Object in Firebase Firestore.

https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase.html

in debug build, the works fine. But release build, the app throws 
"No properties to serialize found on class com.android.billingclient.api.h"

I know, it due to proguard. what rule should i add?

or there any alternative solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46263371/7316675

Comment: @muthukrishnant Hi. Did you find a solution?